# Making average of 3 numbers with 2 decimals (no rounding!)

Tags: c++

This has been on my mind for a week now and i can't seem to understand it.
i have this problem:

```
//1.Make an average of 3 numbers
//2.Display average with two decimals exactly
//3.Average must NOT be rounded

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y ,z, average;
    cin>> x >> y >> z;
    average = (x+y+z)/3;

    cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<< average;

return (0);
}
```

This is what i came up with but apparently it doesn't work 100%. (it rounds up the average sometimes)

Can anyone explain where it fails and how i can fix it?

Comment: So you want to *truncate* the number to two decimals?

Comment: Can you give an example input where the output fails? It seems to work (given what I mean by work), 100%

Comment: Yes, i think this would be the solution. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please include test input and actual vs expected output.

Comment: As a side note, to avoid overflow upon summation of `(x+y+z)`, you should do `(x/3+y/3+z/3)`

Comment: "Average must NOT be rounded" isn't sufficient. What are you supposed to do when the result has more than two significant digits? For example, with 1.0, 1.0, and 1.1, the average is 1.0333... And, incidentally, the stream inserters for floating-point types round the value, so `std::cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << average` **will** round the value.

Comment: @SauravSahu - doing three separate divisions can produce a different value than a non-overflowing sum and a single division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of definition and specification. The division `(x+y+z)/3` is a floating-point one and `setprecision()` obviously rounds the decimal digits, rather than truncates them. You may need to either choose another function (truncating, rather than rounding), or even partially employ a fixed-point logic. Eg if x, y and z are integers, you could use `((x+y+z)*100/3) / 100.0`. (a quite common approach when 'amount' data are represented and processed).

OR (if x, y and z are floats):

```
floor((x+y+z)*100/3)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can do exactly what you are looking for:

```
#include <math.h>
double truncate(double number, int precision) {

    return floor(pow(10, precision) * number) / pow(10, precision);
}
```